# PowerShell string interpolation via a variable

Tags: powershell

The following code works as expected:

```
'John' | % { "$_ $_" }
> John John
```

However, I couldn't work out a way of storing the string `$_ $_` in a variable, which is later used in the pipeline:

```
$f = '$_ $_'
'John' | % { $f }
> $_ $_
```

How would I "interpolate" a variable, instead of using double quoted string?

Answer (score 5):

You can define a PowerShell `ScriptBlock`, enclosed in curly braces, and then execute it using the `.` call operator.

```
$f = { $_ $_ }
'John' | % { . $f }
```

Output looks like:

```
John
John
```

Or, if you want a single string (like your initial question), you can do:

```
$f = { "$_ $_" }
'John' | % { . $f };
```

Output looks like:

```
John John
```

Comment: Why is the semi-colon needed in the second example?

Comment: The semicolon is not a requirement, but it delimits the end of a command in PowerShell.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

```
'John' | % { $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($f) }
> John John
```

Credit goes to Bill_Stewart for his answer to [PowerShell Double Interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168705/double-interpolation-reinterpolation-delayed-interpolation-of-strings).