# Is there a way to create aliases for object methods in powershell?

Tags: powershell, alias

I'm finding that I am repeating myself in powershell scripts in some cases where execution context matters.  Delayed string expansion is one such case:

```
$MyString = 'The $animal says $sound.'

function MakeNoise{ 
   param($animal, $sound)
   $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($MyString)
}

PS> MakeNoise pig oink
The pig says oink.
```

That long `ExpandString()` line gets repeated frequently.  I'd prefer that line to be terse like this:

```
xs($MyString)
xs $MyString
$MyString | xs
```

Any of these would be preferable.  My usual strategies of encapsulation in commandlets don't seem to work for this case because the context of the call to `ExpandString()` is critical.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to create an alias for an object method?
2. Is there some other way call an object's method in a terse manner while preserving the context of the call?

Comment: Why not create a function and call it whatever you want?

Comment: @CB. Because wrapping ExpandString() in a function changes its context rendering the variables to be expanded inaccessible to ExpandString().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need a way to delay evaluating $ExecutionContext until it's time to actually do the string expansion.  Here's one way to do that, implemented as a function:

```
function xs
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   Position=0,
                   Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $string
    )
    process
    {
        $code = "`$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString(`"$string`")"
        [scriptblock]::create($code) 
    }
}
```

Then:

```
&($MyString | xs)
&(xs $MyString)
```

The scriptblock is created at runtime, so $ExecutionContext is evaluated for each invocation.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if `xs` is implemented in a separate module from `$Mystring | xs`.

Comment: That sounds like a scope issue.  It can't fix that.

Comment: I got it working with some minor edits.  I've updated your answer (the update is waiting for peer review).  Your idea to delay invocation by creating a script block for each string definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make your own function for this

```powershell
function xs{
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    [string]$expand)
    $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($expand)
}

function MakeNoise{ 
   param($animal, $sound)
   $MyString = 'The $animal says $sound.'
   xs $MyString
   # $MyString | xs     <--  would also work
}

MakeNoise pig oink
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the `xs` function is only useful if it is in the same context (e.g. module) as `MakeNoise`.  Specifically, if you put `xs` in another module, say, `utility.psm1` and put `MakeNoise` in `MakeNoise.ps1` the result is `The  says .` because `xs` is in a context where `$animal` and `$sound` don't exist.

Comment: You would have that issue for any function or aliases. You could define it as global `function global:xs`. Never played with that much so I'm not sure it will work.

Comment: Hmm...if there existed a Cmdlet called say `Expand-String` that did the same thing as `ExpandString()`, then you could set an alias `xs` for it and it would work the same.  An using an alias to call a funtion doesn't change the context for a function in the same way as wrapping a function in another function does.

Comment: If that was a question the answer is yes. Aliases do not change the functionality of functions/cmdlets. Just decrease typing and brevity is some cases.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the cmdlet New-Alias - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849959.aspx

Comment: `New-Alias` seems to create aliases only for a "cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program".  Do you have an example of how `New-Alias` can be used to create an alias for an object method?